# If I partition a storage device, would BIOS see the partitions as if there are separate physical devices?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios, usb-flash-drive

I have a 2TB flash drive and I'm planning to partition it into three — one as Windows bootable, one as Ubuntu bootable, and one as just normal flash storage.

Now if I will plug it into a laptop, turn it on, then spam F2 to open BIOS, would the BIOS see it as if there are three separate devices?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The BIOS does not know anything about partitions.   On the other hand, if you are talking about UEFI, then yes, it will know of multiple partitions.   UEFI is somewhat like BIOS, and on modern computers handles the booting process - there is normally a small partition set aside for it on the primary disk to facilitate booting multiple OS's as well.

Comment: But could it still detect the flash drive, or not at all?

Comment: I expect it would depend on the UEFI, but in most cases yes.